# Getting error "expected character buffer object" and I don't know why

Tags: python

```
import string

file = open('Text.txt')
dataArray = file.read()
file.close()

dataArray = str(dataArray)
letters = []

qString = ""
for j in dataArray:
    if j.islower() == True:
    qString = qString + "l"
else:
    qString = qString + "u"

for i in range(0,len(dataArray)):
    indexNum = qString.find("luuuluuul")
    letters.append(dataArray[indexNum+4])
    qString.replace(indexNum+4,"-")

print letters
```

I'm programming in python, and attempting to find a sequence of letters in a text file that goes 1 lowercase letter, 3 uppercase letters, 1 lowercase letter, 3 uppercase letters, 1 lowercase letter. What I have should work as far as I know, but it gives an an error "expected character buffer object". I'm wondering if anyone can see where I'm going wrong. The error is ocuring from: 
    qString.replace(indexNum+4,"-")

Comment: What line of code gives you this error? Post the full traceback.

Comment: I got this error a few hours ago when I tried to provide a `list` of delimiters to the `split()` where a single `character` delimiter was expected.

Comment: I suppose that you can reach a bettere result, if you'll use some regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `str.replace` is not for replacing at an index--it's for replacing based on content.

   ```
   >>> "abc".replace("b","44")
   'a44c'
   ```

   The line that gives you your error is `qString.replace(indexNum+4,"-")` for that reason. The most obvious workaround is probably to slice off either side and re-join the pieces back with the new content.
2. Growing a string by repeated appends `q = q + ...` is inefficient. Most of the time what we do instead is

   ```
   pieces = []
   for something in some_things:
       pieces.append(make_piece_of_string(something))
   s = ''.join(pieces)
   ```
3. You do not need to `import string` here.
4. Using `str.find` without checking `if result == -1` is always wrong. Consider using `str.index` instead.
5. Checking `if x == True` is silly (and sometimes buggy)--just check `if x`. In your case, `if j.islower()`.
6. You have an indentation error in the code you posted. Try to post code that is exactly the code you've run (and preferably self-contained, not reading files you don't provide, etc.) to get the best answers possible.